Looking for a novel where a character pitched the idea of building a mass driver on Earth to several different countries
I probably read this story back in the 1980's or 1990's. At the time I was reading the likes of Arthur C. Clark, James P. Hogan, Ben Bova, Harry Harrison, Heinlein, and Larry Niven.
I recall that in the story someone was trying to convince various countries that they had "ideal geography" (such as a really good mountain range) and were thus uniquely positioned to profit from building a mass driver. However, they made the same pitch to several different countries.
I have an inkling that the story might have been "The Moon is a Harsh Mistress" but, I'm not sure. If anyone is familiar with the novel, I'd like to be reminded of some of the specifics of that part of the story (e.g. which countries, which mountain ranges, that kind of thing.).

I'm at a loss why there are votes to reopen this. The questions are very clearly duplicates of each other.

That's like saying "What is the square root or 9?" and "How many musketeers were there?" are duplicates of each other. Two different questions that happen to have the same answer does not make them duplicates.

ID questions are designed to lead you to a final destination. They're marked as duplicates when the place you get to is the same.

The link doesn't support your position. Suppose someone asks a question and the answer is "The Bible". Are you asserting that all subsequent questions where the answer is "The Bible" should be closed as dups?

That is the way things have evolved, that's how Stack Exchange works - yes. (Excepting the Bible would be off-topic as a subject, people don't take kindly to having their deeply cherished beliefs called fantasy or science fiction).

From what I can see, this concept of same-answer-therefore-a-dup is only supported by an old post from Valorum. It doesn't make sense and is clearly not supported by other posts. Also this one. Therefore, I respectfully disagree - this is not the way things have evolved nor is it how Stack Exchange works.

Ever visit Main Meta?

Please note that closing as duplicate is not "an attack."  It says nothing about the quality of your question, purely that it and another question have the same answer.

Well, when a deliberate action is taken that forces the OP to "defend" their post, I don't think that calling that action "an attack" is a misuse of the term.

@DavidW You just rolled back my change to the question? That was inappropriate.

Discussion about the question belongs in comments, or it belongs in meta.  It doesn't belong in the question.

It literally says "edit your question" above. "highlight the difference between the associated question and yours. If edited, your question will be reviewed and might be reopened." You are interfering with the SE process and I respectfully ask that you undo your rollback of my edit.

It is from Heinlein's The Moon is a Harsh Mistress, specifically during the diplomatic mission to Earth by the rebelling moon inhabitants. Mannie says...

Next few weeks I repeated that in a dozen countries, always in private and with implication that it was secret. All that changed was name of mountain. In Ecuador I pointed out that Chimborazo was almost on equator — ideal! But in Argentina I emphasized that their Aconcagua was highest peak in Western Hemisphere. In Bolivia I noted that Altoplano was as high as Tibetan Plateau (almost true), much nearer equator, and offered a wide choice of sites for easy construction leading up to peaks comparable to any on Terra.
I talked to a North American who was a political opponent of that choom who had called us “rabble.” I pointed out that, while Mount McKinley was comparable to anything in Asia or South America, there was much to be said for Mauna Loa — extreme ease of construction. Doubling gees to make it short enough to fit, and Hawaii would be Spaceport of World…whole world, for we talked about day when Mars would be exploited and freight for three (possibly four) planets would channel through their “Big Island.”
Never mentioned Mauna Loa’s volcanic nature; instead I noted that location permitted an aborted load to splash harmlessly in Pacific Ocean.
In Sovunion was only one peak discussed — Lenin, over thousand meters (and rather too close to their big neighbor).
Kilimanjaro, Popocatepetl, Logan, El Libertado — my favorite peak changed by country; all that we required was that it be “highest mountain” in hearts of locals. I found something to say about modest mountains of Chad when we were entertained there and rationalized so well I almost believed it.
 The Moon is a Harsh Mistress - Robert Heinlein

